# Print certain elements of an array that contain a letter

Tags: php, string, printing, contains

I've been working on this problem for a while. Say I needed to create an array that contains Monday, Tuesday, Christmas, and Halloween. The function needs to find and print all entries that contain the string 'day'.

I've gotten the following created.

```
$day = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Christmas', 'Halloween');
```

Then I've tried `in_array` and `str_contains`. I'm kind of lost on this one to be honest.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your snippet:

```
$day = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Christmas', 'Halloween');

foreach ($day as $d) {
    if (strpos($d,'day')) {
        echo $d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what `preg_grep` is built for.  Maybe overkill but works.  Find them and then join on a comma (or whatever) to display:

```
echo implode(', ', preg_grep('/day/', $day));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter` to filter the `$days` array with only `$day` has the word *day* in it with `str_contains`. and join them back with `,`  to display them.

```php
$days = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Christmas', 'Halloween');
echo join(', ', array_filter($days, fn($day)=>str_contains($day, 'day')));
//Monday, Tuesday
```

**Hint:** use [`str_ends_with(haystack, needle)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-ends-with.php) method provided by last version of *PHP v.8* which is do the same `str_contains` but the word we are looking for must be at the end of the string.